# Wordpress, wp_mail send twice

Tags: php, wordpress, email

i'm using this snippet to send email to users when their post deleted, it working but sending the same mail twice, any help please

```
function authorNotification($post_id) {
global $wpdb;
$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$message = "
Hi ".$author->display_name.",
We are sorry to inform you that your article, ".$post->post_title." has been declined. We strongly recommend you to go through the guest posting guidelines before you submit an article again.
";
wp_mail($author->user_email, "Declined", $message);
}
add_action('delete_post', 'authorNotification');
```

Comment: I got the problem where came from, i'm using plugin called Front End PM, and i think he using the same hook for deleted messages, but i still can't figure it out, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you hook into `delete_post` executes as many times as needed.

When you delete a post you also delete all of its revisions therefore the function will be executed more than once if the post has revisions and depending how many it had.

In order to avoid having your function execute each time WordPress deletes posts from the database you can use `did_action( $hook )`.

This function returns the number of times the hook executed. We can use this to fix the multiple-executions problem by placing and if statement.

```
function authorNotification($post_id) {

    global $wpdb;

    $post = get_post($post_id);

    $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);

    $message = "Hi ".$author->display_name.", We are sorry to inform you that your article, ".$post->post_title." has been declined. We strongly recommend you to go through the guest posting guidelines before you submit an article again.";

    if (did_action('delete_post') === 1){
        //only send once
        wp_mail($author->user_email, "Declined", $message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it work after i added add_action('delete_post', 'authorNotification'); at the end of the function, Thanks Orlando P.

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to kill the process after sending mail.

Just add `die();`  after the wp function

```
wp_mail($author->user_email, "Declined", $message);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell whats going wrong here. 
function seems to work properly.

i suspect you are calling the function authorNotification() twice somewhere within your code, maybe delete_post is called twice?

Comment: Thanks for answer, No i didn't used function authorNotification() before, i used before_delete_post hook for the attachments when the posts is deleted, maybe this take effect with delete_post hook?

Comment: That very well could be the case.  
As i do think you call *delete_post* twice somehow.